# Lost majority of r server file code within Docker Container anyway to recover?

Tags: r, docker, rstudio-server

I have been running r-studio through the https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/ container for the past day. I have been saving my code with my local mounted volume, but I'm not sure what happened and I lost about 500 lines of my code from the R file. My .history file doesn't go back that far when I `savehistory()`, but I never restarted my container. Is there anyway to find the console output log from the docker container to attempt to recover some of these functions?

`init git` now.

Comment: Look in all of the volumes of your docker installation, and see if you can find the file. Perhaps under `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` (linux).

Comment: its still running, is there a place within exec -it that I can find a log?

Comment: If you can `docker exec -it` into your container, then ... don't you know the path to check to see if the file is still there? If the file is not, or it is the incomplete file, and you do not have any form of snapshotting going on (some [legacy docker plugins](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/) support them), then the `exec`'d volume is unlikely to be of help. Depending on how you run your container, you might have orphaned volumes hanging around, which is why I suggested you look in the underlying filesystem for (all) volumes, active and inactive.

Comment: so the issue I guess is that I know where the actual file is, and I think I probably deleted half of it accidentally and clicked saved without realizing. I was wondering where the console output from rstudio would go to and if docker saves logs of the console so i can go in and recreate it

Comment: Unfortunately, when I search for `rstudio console log`, I get questions that are often resolved with *"use `sink`"* which is not what you mean. Good luck, I think you might be out 500 lines of code (that stinks).

Comment: yea I've gone through my 7 stages of grief and am coming to terms with it. luckily i had saved some temporary CSVs, now I know for next time